# How to catch SIGABRT inside a nodejs process?

Tags: node.js, sigabrt, node-gyp, libuv

I do hundreds of request per second using the request module in nodejs and sometimes i get the following error

```
nodejs: ../deps/uv/src/unix/async.c:149: uv__async_io: Assertion `n == sizeof(val)' failed.
Code: null Signal: SIGABRT
```

how can i catch the signal?

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: 0.10.35 the latest one

Comment: Same issue. Started coming up in v4 of node. I see process memory consumption going up, followed by SIGABRT and crash.

Answer (score 0):

An assert is blowing up, and that particular one is there to catch programming errors, or totally unexpected conditions. Another user reported this to us, but it turned out it was a missuse of the API. I suggest you open an issue on our bugtracker: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues, ideally with a reproducible reduced test case.